# Angular and Router - unexpected page refresh

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Was struggling until realised that if I bind click event to method that does not exist in my component, Angular refreshes page. I think its because of `routerLink`, because if I remove it, I get an expected error that `method checkUser() does not exist`. Why this happens?

```
<a md-button 
    routerLink="articles" 
    routerLinkActive="menu-active"
    (click)="checkUser()"
    >Articles</a>
```

Comment: You are trying to redirect and mean time trying to call function. Can't you do it same using function only?

Comment: Using a route guard is probably a better place for  `checkUser()`. The behavior you experience is probably because of `routerLink` making an `<a href="...">text</a>` out of your `<a>text</a>`, but your `(click)="checkUser()"` not returning `false` to ensure `preventDefault()` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `routerLink` directive applied to an `a` element sets an `href` attribute upon this element.

I guess the same exception is thrown on click but the event still bubbles up and then the default behavior is executed and the page location is changed. As this happens really fast, you don't notice the error.

Try preserving the console logs even after page relaod, the error should be there.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with unexpecting Angular app reloading. The problem was in `type="submit"`. I've changed it to `type="button"` and the problem is gone.
Was:

```
<button type="submit" (click)="onAddItem()" >Add</button>
```

Become:

```
<button type="button" (click)="onAddItem()" >Add</button>
```